# displaying output form rules to a TextBox

Tags: c#

I need help on how to display output from a rules engine to a form element in visual C#. I am developing a decision support system using visual C# 2010 and drools.net for the rules engine.

Comment: What do you have so far? Post some work and you'll get more answers

Comment: Im a computer science student new to coding. I will definitely post some work but i need help on this one

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before where I had XML representations of my forms and then dynamically created them when the rules engine needed to render a form. On the reverse side I wrote a JavaScript library to parse the form and output an xml document that contained the field values and then passed it back to the rules engine.

Comment: Did you pass the xml form representation to the rules engine as part of the rules?